# make query to display greatest data in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, max, ms-access-2016

I have a table in access:

```
 id | holiday
-----|----------
2020 | 40
2020 | 39
4644 | 23
4644 | 22
```

I want my query  to display the greatest value for holiday

something like this:

```
  id | holiday
-----|----------
2020 | 40
4644 | 23
```

any ideas would be highly appreciated. Perhaps using sql in acccess?

Comment: `Select max(holiday) mx from table1` you could research this. your question brings no value to this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a basic aggregation query:

```
select id, max(holiday) max_holiday
from mytable
group by id
```